# Can't install Perf on Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, perf

I tried different ways to install perf but they are all failed:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# perf
/usr/bin/perf: line 13: exec: perf_5.3: not found
E: linux-perf-5.3 is not installed.

root@kali:~/Desktop# apt-get install linux-perf-4.19
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-perf-4.19
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-perf-4.19'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-perf-4.1

root@kali:~/Desktop# sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster InRelease
Get:2 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Reading package lists... Done       
E: Release file for http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 1d 3h 24min 55s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

root@kali:~/Desktop# sudo apt install linux-tools-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-common
```

Could someone point out the issue?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Why are you so sure the package name is `linux-perf-4.19` (in particular since `perf_5.3` seems to be expected)? Did you try `apt-cache search perf` to identify available package versions? Also, look at the "Release file ... is not valid yet" message, you may be facing a clock issue that prevents `apt` from accepting the repository.

Comment: @CSDUG I had the same problem, turns out I had to run `perf_5.5` instead of just `perf`.  Try typing `perf` and hitting TAB to see if there are any other versions installed.